# office webservice don't return body info

Tags: vb.net, web-services, office365, exchangewebservices

I used this code to retrieve information from a meeting in Office365,
but all fields about body and attendees are empty with a exception.
Have you any ideas ??

```
Dim svc As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
        svc.Credentials = New WebCredentials(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailUsername"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailPassword"))
        svc.Url = New Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx")

        Dim startDate As Date = Now
        Dim endDate As Date = Now.AddDays(2)

        Dim calendar As CalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(svc, WellKnownFolderName.Calendar) ', New PropertySet())

        Dim cView As New CalendarView(startDate, endDate, 50)
        cView.PropertySet = New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties) 
        Dim appointments As FindItemsResults(Of Appointment) = calendar.FindAppointments(cView)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Body and Attendees aren't returned with you using FindAppointments (or FindItems). To get this you need to either make a further GetItem (Load) request on Each item or better using LoadPropertiesForItems eg something like

```
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = service.FindAppointments(
WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,
new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)));

service.LoadPropertiesForItems(
from Item item in findResults select item,
PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```